# How to get schema or processed Nested json file compressed(gzip) stored in s3 using AWS glue?

Tags: json, compression, aws-glue, amazon-athena

How to get schema or processed Nested json file compressed(gzip)  stored in s3 using AWS glue?

I wanted to get schema of nested json compressed (gzip) file, stored in s3 using aws glue or any other tool and then use that schema in Athena to analyze the data?

Is there any way with out writng zeepline code 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get that schema is to use a Glue Crawler. You can create a crawler pointing it to the path in s3 i.e the include path on a crawler: See the following for details: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html